# How to use native windows commands in VsCode`?

Tags: cmd, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have installed a command prompt shell in Visual Code and I have a compiler that I usually run from the windows cmd. I'm wondering how can I make the windows commands (and my own) that works in cmd run in the Visual Code Command prompt?

[image]

Comment: Please do at least a basic search for the error message before posting. This question has been [asked and answered here before](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command) - there are more than 6000 results for that search. Surely at least one of them would help you find a solution.

Comment: I actually did research it a lot, I found it very hard to find any good answers for inside VScode environment. I know why the error occurs, it doesn't know the path. I'm wondering how to solve this and if there's a way to add all the paths that exist in windows cmd already to visual studio.